# Mongo query to return latest entry

Tags: mongodb

Hi I have the following data structure in mongodb:

```
{
"_id" : "4087322f-1ad0-4595-935f-b41ef6d87306",
"lastModifiedDate" : ISODate("2016-11-22T20:48:05.904Z"),
"notes" : " I do not like him that much",
"peopleId" : "1121",
"status" : "asses"
}
```

I wish to query the data such that it will return the latest value for each peopleId which also matches a chosen status. I've been looking into $group however doing the equal status is causing some issue.

I have got as far as grouping the values by peopleId using:

```
.aggregate([      
            {$group : {_id : "$peopleId", "allData" : {$push : "$$ROOT"}}},
            {$sort : { lastModifiedDate : -1}}     
           ]).pretty()
```

To give give me these results:

```
{
    "_id" : "1123",
    "allData" : [
        {
            "_id" : "c9d6a6ce-104d-414a-8d89-512e556d7aba",
            "lastModifiedDate" : ISODate("2016-11-22T20:55:35.662Z"),
            "notes" : "He's in!",
            "peopleId" : "1123",
            "status" : "done"
        },
        {
            "_id" : "14e522d8-6cae-42ee-ad52-d5cf3cae0c29",
            "lastModifiedDate" : ISODate("2016-11-22T20:56:46.128Z"),
            "notes" : "He's in!",
            "peopleId" : "1123",
            "status" : "asses"
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : "1121",
    "allData" : [
        {
            "_id" : "d2c3e5da-8696-4dcc-a5cd-1f2657f0192c",
            "lastModifiedDate" : ISODate("2016-11-22T20:46:35.097Z"),
            "notes" : " I do not like him",
            "peopleId" : "1121",
            "status" : "pending"
        },
        {
            "_id" : "4087322f-1ad0-4595-935f-b41ef6d87306",
            "lastModifiedDate" : ISODate("2016-11-22T20:48:05.904Z"),
            "notes" : " I do not like him that much",
            "peopleId" : "1121",
            "status" : "asses"
        },
        {
            "_id" : "be4fa5bd-da8c-4c1a-9010-6a86afd11dbc",
            "lastModifiedDate" : ISODate("2016-11-22T20:49:27.268Z"),
            "notes" : "He's in!\nTue Nov 22 12:49:27 PST 2016 He's TF OUT",
            "peopleId" : "1121",
            "status" : "done"
        }
    ]
}
```

From this I need to extract the most recent entry based on lastModifiedDate and then check that is matches a given status.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far? In general the approach for returning the latest entry involves sorting by date in descending order and returning only the first value from the result.

Comment: you no need to do $grouping. you should adopt the simplest approach as mentioned by @Strezel. sort data in descending order by lastModifiedDate and limit the record to 1 and you will get the latest modified document.

Comment: I've added some more details to the question I hope this clarifies

Comment: will you can slice the all data array as i showed in my comment for my other answer. give it a look.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the solutions.

**Solution 1:-**

If you want all the fields in the collection in the output.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$match : {"status" : "asses"}},
    {$sort : {peopleId : 1, lastModifiedDate : -1}},
    {$group : {_id : "$peopleId", "allData" : {$push : "$$ROOT"}}},
    {$project: {_id :0, allData : {$slice : ["$allData", 0, 1]}}}
]);
```

**Output:-**

```
{
    "allData" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5834c004ba41f1f22e600c7f"),
            "lastModifiedDate" : ISODate("2016-11-24T20:48:05.904Z"),
            "notes" : " I do not like him that much",
            "peopleId" : "1",
            "status" : "asses"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Solution 2:-**

If you don't want all the fields from the collection in the output.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$match : {"status" : "asses"}},
    {$sort : {peopleId : 1, lastModifiedDate : -1}},
    {$group : {_id : "$peopleId", lastModDate : {$first : "$lastModifiedDate"}}}
])
```

**Output:-**

```
{
    "_id" : "1",
    "lastModDate" : ISODate("2016-11-24T20:48:05.904Z")
}
```

Comment: thanks for the solutions not what I wanted but got me close. this line .aggregate([      {$group : {_id : "$peopleId", "allData" : {$push : "$$ROOT"}}}  ]).pretty() gives me a an array of the values for each people Id, I need to then extract the most recent of these of Lastmodified once this is done I need to check if it equals the correct status. I am having trouble referring to the inner sort of the array I have tried few variations of  {$sort : { allData.lastModifiedDate : -1}}, but no luck so far.

Comment: I have also added some more details to the question

Answer (score 0):

i created a collection with following docs

```
{ "_id" : "4087322f-1ad0-4595-935f-b41ef6d87306", "lastModifiedDate" : ISODate("2016-11-22T20:48:05.904Z"), "notes" : " I do not like him that much",
"peopleId" : "1121", "status" : "asses" }
{ "_id" : "4087322f-1ad0-4595-935f-b41ef6d87305", "lastModifiedDate" : ISODate("2016-10-22T20:48:05.904Z"), "notes" : " I do not like him that much",
"peopleId" : "1121", "status" : "asses" }
{ "_id" : "4087322f-1ad0-4595-935f-b41ef6d87304", "lastModifiedDate" : ISODate("2016-11-21T20:48:05.904Z"), "notes" : " I do not like him that much",
"peopleId" : "1121", "status" : "asses" }
```

and if i execute the following query

```
db.mel.find().sort({lastModifiedDate:-1}).limit(1)
```

it gives me

```
{ "_id" : "4087322f-1ad0-4595-935f-b41ef6d87306", "lastModifiedDate" : ISODate("2016-11-22T20:48:05.904Z"), "notes" : " I do not like him that much",
"peopleId" : "1121", "status" : "asses" }
```

which is latest as per the lastmodifeddate.

Comment: I need to do it for each peopleId

Comment: will you be having multiple records with same peopleId ?

Comment: db.mel.aggregate([
    { "$sort": { "lastModifiedDate": -1 } },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$peopleId",
        "results": {
            "$push": {
                "notes": "$notes", 
                "lastModifiedDate": "$lastModifiedDate",
                "id": "$id",
    "status":"$status",
    "peopleId":"$peopleId"
            }
        }
    }},
    { "$project": {
        "results": { "$slice": [ "$results", 2 ] }
    }}
])